# Trying to install DCS Agent software using VB Script

Tags: vbscript

Trying to install a software remotely. Need to change some properties of software while installing silently. We written code as below in VBScript 
spath = """" & pathofEXEfile & """ /s /v"/qn" /v"PROPERTY=value" /v"PROPERTY=value""
obj.run(spath,0,true)

When we try to run above code,getting compilation error "Expected End of Statement".
Please help us to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You start to obey the rule "quote double quotes by doubling them" but forget about it in the second part of the string:

```
>> spath = """" & pathofEXEfile & """ /s /v"/qn" /v"PROPERTY=value" /v"PROPERTY=value""
>>
Error Number:       1025
Error Description:  Expected end of statement
>> spath = """" & pathofEXEfile & """ /s /v""/qn"" /v""PROPERTY=value"" /v""PROPERTY=value"""
>>
>> WScript.Echo spath
>>
"" /s /v"/qn" /v"PROPERTY=value" /v"PROPERTY=value"
>>
```